# Live video streaming from a Linux server running Apache

Tags: php, javascript, apache, webcam, live-video

I just want to connect a couple of cameras to my apache server, embed some code in a PHP page and stream live video to the internet.

Does anyone know any simple affordable solutions that don't involve Microsoft of Flash?

Comment: To some degree I think this depends largely on the cameras you are using and what software/streaming access they provide.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Stack isn't really for answering people who haven't helped themselves at least a little. Perhaps you could at least say what you have looked at and why *not* flash?

Comment: I've done plenty of research.  I left the question so open because I thought the answers would be helpful to more people than if I asked something really specific.  I don't want to use flash because I want it to work on iPhones.

Comment: Just to give a background: I bought an old arcade teddy bear crane machine and wired it up to a computer.  I want to let people play it online and the only bit of the puzzle left to figure out is how to let people see it.  The player can move a virtual joystick around and then hit go - then the commands get sent to the arcade machine.

Answer (score 0):

For *live streaming* you need flash or silverlight on the client side, except the iOS devices, where it's doable with HTML5.

Based on your comment, it looks like you'll need a mixed solution. Flash for the normal devices, and HTML5+m3u8 for iOS.

Comment: This is incorrect. HTML5 is widely supported now so as long as you are only targeting newer browsers, HTML5 would be acceptable.

Comment: @Julian Knight: incorrect :) HTML5 *is* widely supported. but the video format that can be used for *live streaming* is **not**.

Comment: Sorry to disagree but this is not right. Streaming in WebM format *is* supported in Firefox but not H.265. Chrome is fully supported, so is IE9. According to [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/html5) so is Safari and Opera.

Comment: @Julian Knight: he has a **live stream**. what's the format you can use in IE9 and Opera, etc..?

Comment: [stream.m a WebM live streaming server](http://code.google.com/p/stream-m/) ? Also see http://www.webmproject.org/tools/

Comment: Not tried it myself which is why I'm not answering the question. However, WebM & H.265 is supported by IE9 and there is software to live stream from a webcam in WebM and H.265 formats.

Comment: @Julian Knight: no, it's not directly supported, extra install is needed. http://www.webmproject.org/ie/#why-do-i-need-these-components-to-play-webm-in-ie9 and https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf/

Comment: Drat, just retested IE9, no WebM, my mistake. Pain. You'd need to support both which won't be so easy!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13564/discussion-between-karoly-horvath-and-julian-knight)